# Why is .on() Not working as expected in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've just started learning jQuery. And below is the code that i tried for attaching the events "mouseover" and "mouseout" for the div elements added dynamically. But when I tried running this in browser, i got no results. I dont know what is goin wrong... I hit a search for the use and syntax of using .on() of jquery and no favourable results.. Can anyone tell me, how to make my below code work?..

```
    <html>
       <head>
          <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
             $(function(){
                 $("#divid").on("mouseover",".test", function(){
                     $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
                 }).on("mouseout",".test", function(){
                     $(this).css("background-color", "white");
                });
             });

             function AddBox(){
                var div = $("<div></div>").addClass("test").text("Another box");
                $("#divTestArea1").append(div);
             }
          </script>
      </head>
      <body>
         <div id="divTestArea1">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="AddBox();">Add box</a>
            <div class="test" id="divid">This is a colored box</div>
         </div>
      </body>
   </html>
```

Thanks in Advance...;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem here,

you are adding dynamic div to `#divTestArea1` here `$("#divTestArea1").append(div);`

but you are delegating your event to  `#divid` so this search for div class test inside `<div id=divid>` which is not there.

try this

```
 $("#divTestArea1").on("mouseover",".test", function(){
   ....
  }
```

with this, you are delegating the mouseover event of `.test` div to`#divTestArea1` ..which is what we need.. and should work...

Comment: :| I cannot post my fiddle it keeps saying must accompanied with code.. wew now it's too late..